# Replacing text in multiple Word files

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to vba and I've been trying to figure out a code to search and replace text in multiple Word files that are in different subfolders in a main folder. My problem is that when I run my code, it seems to open each file a lot of times before moving on to the next one (or loops a few times in the same subfolder before moving on to the next one); however this doesn't happen when I run the code line by line which has really left me at a loss; hopefully someone can provide some answers.

```
Sub DoLangesNow()
   Dim file
   Dim path As String
   Dim StrFolder As String
   Dim strSubFolder As String
   Dim strFile As String
   Dim colSubFolders As New Collection
   Dim varItem As Variant
   Dim myStoryRange As Range

     ' Parent folder
        StrFolder = "G:\Caminos de San Lorenzo II\"

     ' Loop through the subfolders 
        strSubFolder = Dir(StrFolder & "*", vbDirectory)

       Do While Not strSubFolder = ""
         Select Case strSubFolder
             Case ".", ".."
             ' Current folder or parent folder - ignore
             Case Else
             ' Add to collection
             colSubFolders.Add Item:=strSubFolder, Key:=strSubFolder
         End Select
     ' On to the next one
     strSubFolder = Dir
 Loop
 ' Loop through the collection
 For Each varItem In colSubFolders
     ' Loop through files in subfolder
     strFile = Dir(StrFolder & varItem & "\" & "*.doc")
     Do While strFile <> ""
     Set file = Documents.Open(FileName:=StrFolder & _varItem & "\" & strFile)
 ' Start of macro replace text x  with y
  For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "EDIFICIO CAPINURI"
        .Replacement.Text = "CONJUNTO RESIDENCIAL LOS CAMINOS DE SAN LORENZO II"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "Olga Márquez"
        .Replacement.Text = "Glady Rubiano"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "OLGA LEONOR MÁRQUEZ PAVA"
        .Replacement.Text = "GLADY MOLINA RUBIANO"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "830.005.582-9"
        .Replacement.Text = "830.065.826-7"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "Carrera 53 # 134 A - 71"
        .Replacement.Text = "Calle 146 A # 58 B - 85"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "2588540"
        .Replacement.Text = "6241551"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "313 4314549"
        .Replacement.Text = "312 4680338"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = " 24149562"
        .Replacement.Text = "0"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "capinuriph@gmail.com"
        .Replacement.Text = "caminosdesanlorenzodos@gmail.com"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "Positiva"
        .Replacement.Text = "Positiva"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = " ADMINISTRADORA"
        .Replacement.Text = "ADMINISTRADORA"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
         Next myStoryRange
   ' End of macro 1
   ' Saves the file
         ActiveDocument.Save
         ActiveDocument.Close , (SaveChanges)
        ' set file to next in Dir
         strFile = Dir
       Loop
   Next varItem

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think the code is opening files more than once, or looping more than once? Have you tried putting Debug.Print or MsgBox statements into your code to substantiate this and find out where the behavior is happening?

Comment: @Cindy Meister, as I said, I'm really new to vba so most of this code was me trying to join existing codes already and fitting them to my needs. The code is definitely opening files more than once because when I run it, it will show me which files are being opened and I see them being opened, saved, closed and reopened again only to go through the same loop.

Comment: Do you know what I mean when I say "Comment out line xyz of your code" (the xyz isn't important - just "comment out")?

Comment: As in placing an apostrophe?

Comment: Yes :-) In the For...Each loop comment out everything you're doing with the Word document, from opening it through saving and closing. That leaves only the lines that loop the files. After `For Each varItem In colSubFolders` add a line: `Debug.Print varItem` and after `Do While strFile <> ""` add a line: `Debug.Print strFile`. This will write the contents of the collection (folder names) and the file names to the Immediate Window of the VBA Editor (Ctrl+G to toggle on/off). Can you see if anything is in there more than once?

Comment: You're right, they appear there only once. Does that mean the problem is in the .Find.Text block?

Comment: Change wdFindContinue to wdFindStop and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: So I posted the code I ended up working with and at first it seemed to work fine, but then I tested it on another folder and again I have the same problem. This time the Debug.Print function does show the files are being opened more than once "randomly".  I played with it a bit and it's the "ActiveDocument.Save/ActiveDocument.Close" part that messes it up and I don't know why. Whenever I left those two out, the files remain open and the code works just fine (tho it takes a bit longer since opening up so many files uses more memory)

Comment: Probably because the loop is "hitting" the same files again, after they've been saved and closed. Try creating a new folder and use SaveAs to save the files to it. OR do both loops to get a list of files (complete with path) in an array or collection. The loop the array, getting the file names and opening the documents. Then saving the documents won't affect what `Dir` is picking up.

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why is that happening? It just seems so random, with some files it does with some it doesn't and I cannot seemmm to find a pattern. I'll read moe on array and collections and see if I can get anything done with that.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up looking through more posts online about finding and replacing words in multiple files/subfolders/folders and finally ended up with this which seems to work just fine:

```
Sub DoLangesNow()
    Dim file
    Dim path As String
    Dim StrFolder As String
    Dim strSubFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim colSubFolders As New Collection
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim myStoryRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TargetList
    Dim MyRange As Range
    TargetList = Array("EDIFICIO CAPINURI", "Olga Márquez", "OLGA LEONOR MÁRQUEZ PAVA", "830.005.582-9", "Carrera 53 # 134 A - 71", "2588540", "313 4314549", "24149562", "capinuriph@gmail.com", "Positiva", "ADMINISTRADORA", "POSITIVA") ' put list of terms to find here
    Dim sStringToAdd
    sStringToAdd = Array("EDIFICIO TORRE 95", "Claudia Cárdenas", "CLAUDIA CARDENAS PEREZ", "959.011.545-0", "Calle 95 # 21 - 34", "-", "3043982237", "51798184", "aedyco@yahoo.com", "Positiva", "ADMINISTRADORA", "POSITIVA")


    ' Parent folder
    StrFolder = "G:\Prueba\"

    ' Loop through the subfolders
    strSubFolder = Dir(StrFolder & "*", vbDirectory)

    Do While Not strSubFolder = ""
        Select Case strSubFolder
            Case ".", ".."
                ' Current folder or parent folder - ignore
            Case Else
                ' Add to collection
                colSubFolders.Add Item:=strSubFolder, Key:=strSubFolder
        End Select
        ' On to the next one
        strSubFolder = Dir
    Loop
    ' Loop through the collection
    For Each varItem In colSubFolders
        Debug.Print varItem
        ' Loop through files in subfolder
        strFile = Dir(StrFolder & varItem & "\" & "*.doc")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Debug.Print strFile
            Set file = Documents.Open(FileName:=StrFolder & varItem & "\" & strFile)
            ' Start of macro replace text x  with y

            For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

                Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Content

                MyRange.Find.Execute FindText:=TargetList(i), ReplaceWith:=sStringToAdd(i), _
                                     Replace:=wdReplaceAll

                Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

                MyRange.Find.Execute FindText:=TargetList(i), ReplaceWith:=sStringToAdd(i), _
                                     Replace:=wdReplaceAll

                Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

                MyRange.Find.Execute FindText:=TargetList(i), ReplaceWith:=sStringToAdd(i), _
                                    Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next i


            '   ' End of macro 1
            '   ' Saves the file
            ActiveDocument.Save
            ActiveDocument.Close
            ' set file to next in Dir
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next varItem
End Sub
```

Thanks to Cindy Meister for her help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do a find/replace on one single document it’s no big deal.  However, if you have to do that for all Word documents in a folder it could be a very big deal.  The script below is a batch process that does a find/replace routine on all the Word files in a folder.

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

    Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 100) As String 
'100 files is the maximum applying this code
    On Error Resume Next
Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With MyDialog
        .Filters.Clear
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        i = 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
                i = i + 1
            Next
            i = i - 1
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For j = 1 To i Step 1
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = "Marriott International" 'Find What
                .Replacement.Text = "Marriott" 'Replace With
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindAsk
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchByte = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
ActiveDocument.Save
            ActiveWindow.Close
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever I try to adjust this or any other type of code to look for files through sub folders i end up with the same problem. Some files are opened multiple times during the loop before moving on to the next sub folder.